# TYPO3 fluid get @attributes

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to get attributes from an xml feed.
If i f:debug the Array in fluid, i can see the attributes as an array with the name @attributes:

```
array(6 items)
  title => 'Test Title'
  enclosure => array(1 item)
  @attributes => array(3 items)
     url => 'http://www.example.com/test.jpg' (55 chars)
     length => '83423' (5 chars)
     type => 'image/jpeg' (10 chars)
```

But it is not possible to read the url with this syntax:

```
enclosure.@attributes.url
```

Maybe it is the @ sign.
Is there a Viewhelper (maybe VHS) or something i can use to read the data?

Comment: Have you already tried to iterate over enclosure with <f:for each="{enclosure}" as="attributes"> ... <for each="{attributes} as="attribute"> ...

Comment: This is a SimpleXMLElement. What u get when u `<f:debug>{enclosure.@attributes}</f:debug>` also see this: http://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=660534& . Also if you have a controller, you should use the standard SimpleXMLElement functions and give the template a real array or just the values you need.

Comment: As my way seems to work the alternative solution @nbar mentioned is more clean.

Comment: Yes, but i have no access to the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Christoph. This solution works:

```
<f:for each="{rss_news.enclosure}" as="item">
     <img src="{item.url}" alt="">
</f:for>
```